# How to filter and replace values in json with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have problems filtering and updating the content of a json file using jq. I need to filter json data based on specific values, and based on that filter edit other values and increment others

I have tried to use

```
jq '.[] | select (."name"| contains("CHANNEL1"))'
```

to filter but the result is missing the top key "x-ID.0" info, the result is the following :

```
{
  "_file.name": "filename.ext",
  "name": "CHANNEL1 HD TV",
  "logo": "file.png",
  "x-channelID": "726"
}
{
  "_file.m3u.name": "filename.ext",
  "name": "CHANNEL1 SD",
  "logo": "file.png",
  "x-channelID": "726"
}
```

For renumbering i have tested the function below and it works well

```
jq -n -s '[ foreach inputs[] as $i (100; .+1; $i*{"x-channelID":(.-1)}) ]'
```

Here is the original json file

```
{
  "x-ID.0": {
    "_file.name": "filename.ext",
    "name": "CHANNEL1 HD TV",
    "logo": "file.png",
    "x-channelID": "726"
  },
   "x-ID.2": {
    "_file.m3u.name": "filename.ext",
    "name": "CHANNEL2",
    "logo": "file.png",
    "x-channelID": "106"
  },
   "x-ID.3": {
    "_file.m3u.name": "filename.ext",
    "name": "CHANNEL3 SD",
    "logo": "file.png",
    "x-channelID": "236"
  },
   "x-ID.4": {
    "_file.m3u.name": "filename.ext",
    "name": "CHANNEL1 SD",
    "logo": "file.png",
    "x-channelID": "726"
  },
   "x-ID.5": {
    "_file.m3u.name": "filename.ext",
    "name": "CHANNEL2 HD",
    "logo": "file.png",
    "x-channelID": "726"
  }
}
```

here is the expected the result

```
{
  "x-ID.0": {
    "_file.m3u.name": "filename.ext",
    "name": "CHANNEL1 HD",
    "logo": "CHANNEL1.png",
    "x-channelID": "100"
  },
   "x-ID.4": {
    "_file.m3u.name": "filename.ext",
    "name": "CHANNEL1 SD",
    "logo": "CHANNEL1.png",
    "x-channelID": "101"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
to_entries | map(select(.value.name|strings|contains("CHANNEL1"))) | [foreach .[] as $keyvalue (99; .+1; { key: $keyvalue.key, value: ($keyvalue.value + {"x-channelID": .})})] | from_entries
```

`to_entries` map your object into an array of `{ key: "key", value: "value" }` items.

`map(select(filter))` filter those whose value match your criteria.

We then use `foreach` to increment a counter while we iterate over the remaining key/value pairs and update the x-channelID field of the values with the counter.

Finally we use `from_entries` to recreate the desired object from the array of key/value pairs.

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/VTxvuAo0T2).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202106/discussion-on-answer-by-aaron-how-to-filter-and-replace-values-in-json-with-jq).